# Error while uploading multiple documents in Oracle webcenter content(UCM) via Desktop integration suite(DIT)

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, webcenter, oracle-ucm, desktop-integration

I'm facing two issues while uploading multiple documents in Oracle webcenter content(UCM) via Desktop integration suite(DIT)

1) multiple file uploads are not taking the content information and not replicating the same for e.g. metadata field "Title" appear itself as null_null_null_null
2) files are not visible under the required folders.

I haven't done any customization and using default product Oracle webcenter content. Is their any bug/issue with product. If those who have used DIT with Oracle UCM can throw some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scenario was when documents were uploaded via client DIS, option to 'populate metadata' was not configured. Hence, check-in metadata fields were not asked from the end user and title which was taking its name from the metadata fields took null values with respect to each left metadata field.

But can we configure settings to populate metadata as an administrator for all end users rather than doing it on each client DIS?

Comment: You should be able to set "Prompt for Metadata" on each folder you want this to happen for.

Answer (score 2):

What specific version/patchset of WebCenter Content are you running? You can find this by navigating to Administration -> Configuration for instance_name.

Do you have any errors in the Content Server Logs that pertain to this?

Comment: Aplogies @jonathan-hult and oranob for late reply. I'm at client location. to answer- WCC version is 11gR1-11.1.1.6.0 and just get below logs while uploading.        !csInvalidPreCheckinField,dSource
!csMonitorTotalRequests,24,0,0.19997499883174896,0.09537500143051147,1
Request Audit Report over the last 120 Seconds for server wcoscmstkcosiskeysightcom16209****
-Num Requests 24 Errors 0 Reqs/sec. 0.19997499883174896 Avg. Latency (secs) 0.09537500143051147 Max Thread Count 1                 !

Comment: in content server gets warning: csInvalidPreCheckinField(dSource)                    DIS version is 11.1.8

Comment: Also , while downloading DIS client from webcenter front end ->My downloads -> DIS do not work at all. version is 11.1.6 however i have got a DIS setup version 11.1.8 from a friend via which uploading files give me this 'null_null_null'  issue. do i need to make any configuration changes? is there an option to populate metadata in DIS

Comment: What's the full stack trace for the csInvalidPreCheckinField error?

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the above. Check your content server logs.
Sounds likely you are missing metadata either because it hasn't been inherited or simply not set.